# How mock Kotlin extension function in interface?

Tags: kotlin, mockito, powermock, mockk

I have an extension function for interface like the following:

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

fun ConnectionFactory.foo() {
    println("do some stuff")
}
```

How can I mock the function foo?

Please note, I have seen approaches for classes and objects in http://mockk.io/#extension-functions, but it does not work. I have tried this one:

```
import io.mockk.classMockk
import io.mockk.every
import org.junit.Test
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

class ExtensionFunctionTest {
@Test
fun mockExtensionFunction() {
    val connectionFactory = classMockk(ConnectionFactory::class)
    every { connectionFactory.foo() } returns println("do other stuff")
    connectionFactory.foo()
}
}
```

It throws exception:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

Comment: what's the file name from where your extension function is? Is this the full verifiable example, or is the class different?

Comment: The function is defined outside of the class ConnectionFactory and is module wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/oleksiyp/mockk#extension-functions) in case of module wide extension functions you need to `staticMock` "hidden" class created for an extension function.
Here is an example (assuming the file name is `com/sample/extmockingtest/SampleTest.kt`):

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.foo(): String  = "do some stuff"

class ExtensionFunctionTest {
    @Test
    fun mockExtensionFunction() {
        val itMock = classMockk(Iterable::class);
        staticMockk("com.sample.extmockingtest.SampleTestKt").use {
            every {
                itMock.foo()
            } returns "do other stuff"

            assertEquals("do other stuff", itMock.foo())

            verify {
                itMock.foo()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the defined implementation of the interface `listOf(1, 2, 3)`, but can we mock on an interface, like `Iterable<T>.foo()` ?

Comment: Sure, we may replace `listOf()` with `val itMock = classMockk(Iterable::class)`. Then we can use this mock inside `every` and `verify`. I've updated original code example to cover this case.